# Why TextView is missing?

Tags: android, textview, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I'am setting the text to TextView and EditText programmatically. but those widgets are not visible. If i take android:layout_marginTop="100dp" for Textview, then i'am able to see those widgets. Why so? Can you suggest me any other way. Thanks in advance.

```
*<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@color/homepage_background">

<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<!--  This Textview is not visible -->
        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/updateText"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="@color/homepage_labelText"
            android:layout_gravity="center" android:gravity="center"
             />
 <!--  This EditText box also not visible (only half) -->
        <EditText android:id="@+id/previousText" android:textColor="@color/homepage_labelText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:cursorVisible="false" android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:maxLines="2"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="@color/homepage_labelText" android:text="Complaint"
            android:layout_gravity="center" android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
        <EditText android:id="@+id/updateEditText" android:lines="5"
            android:focusable="true" android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:gravity="top" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:hint="Enter to update complaint info              " />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center" android:background="@color/homepage_title_background"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
    <Button android:id="@+id/updateComplaintSubmitButton"
        android:text="  Update  " android:textColor="@color/homepage_labelText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="40dp" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/updateComplaintCancelButton"
        android:text="  Cancel  " android:textColor="@color/homepage_labelText"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>*
```

Comment: Maybe post the code you are using to show/hide these widgets. I copy/pasted your layout file and it works fine

Comment: Here is my code to set the text programmatically                                                 String number = getIntent().getExtras().getString("com_number");
String nature = getIntent().getExtras().getString("com_nature");
String description = getIntent().getExtras().getString("com_description");

TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.updateText);
tv.setText(nature + " : " + "#" + number);

EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.previousText);
et.setText(description);
et.setKeyListener(null);

Answer (score 1):

I think I have the same problem and it comes from the gravity property of your TextView.. it is set to center. I don't know for sure why android is hiding the TextView in this case and I am trying to fix this as well